# In a Ruby Rails App, I am getting "project/app/controllers/workouts_controller.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So I've looked all through Stack Overflow trying to find a reason why I would be hitting a parsing error. This is a relatively new Rails app, but I don't think I've missed any configuration as I've been able to deploy on Heroku successfully.

From previous Stackoverflow posts it would seem that I have an extra end since Rails is complaining that it is finding an end when it is expecting the end of the file. I tried taking out the last end (which is the closer for the controller class itself) as well as commenting various parts of the code in and out and it just simply isn't working. Does anyone have any ideas/advice on how to circumvent/solve this issue?

Here is my controller file

```
Class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    id = params[:id] # retrieve workout ID from URI route
    @workout = Workout.find(id) # look up workout by unique ID
    # will render app/views/workouts/show.<extension> by default
  end

  def index
    @all_workouts = Workout.all_workouts
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  def new
    # default: render 'new' template
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.create!(params[:workout])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@workout.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to workouts_path
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @workout = Workout.find params[:id]
    @workout.update_attributes!(params[:workout])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@workout.title} was successfully updated."
    redirect_to workouts_path(@workout)
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
    @workout.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Workout '#{@workout.title}' destroyed."
    redirect_to workouts_path
  end


end
```

This probably isn't needed, but here is my model file:

```
Class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :title, :time, :creator, :exercise_list

  def self.all_exercises
    %w(push-ups pull-ups crunches rest)
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use http://runnable.com/ to set up a testcase (http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/). Also try including the full error / stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
```

with

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
```

Same for your model. `class` keyword should be used in lower register.
I assume you misprinted it, thats why parser sees extra `end` keyword

Comment: Had to change it in both. Worked like a charm. Thanks!